# Showing that $f:\mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ given by $f(x)=[3x]$ is function?

Tags: functions

How can I show this is a function?

$f:\mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ given by $f([x]_4)=[3x]_2$

where $[x]_n$ is the equivalence class of $x\mod n$.

I think it is a function because I cannot find a counter example and

because all element in equivalence class 1 mod 4 is same as 1 mod 2

$1 \mod 4=(-7,-3,1,5,9,13,7,.....)$

$1 \mod 2=(-7,-5,-3,-1,13,5,7,8,11,13,15,17,19,21,.....)$

so you plug $f(3)=3(5)=15$

15 is in class 1 mod 2 as an example.

So then to do a proof I would do

Let x be an an integer.

$x\in[y]\iff 4\div(x-y)$

But I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Be careful when you write "$1/2 \bmod{2}$", since $2$ doesn't have a multiplicative inverse here.

Comment: Yes, writing $1/2$ is nonsense, $\pmod 2$.

Comment: Yes mod is integers I forget

Comment: I guess Ill edit that part out of my attemted proof

Comment: @FernandoMartinez It's easiest to demonstrate it is the composite of two well-defined functions rather than directly from the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f$ is a function, you need only prove that it is well-defined. That is:
$$
x= y \implies f(x) = f(y)
$$

You want to show $3x = 3y \pmod{2}$, given that $x = y \pmod{4}$. By definition, this is just showing that $3x-3y = 2k$ for some integer $k$ whenever $x-y = 4n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Consider
$$
3x-3y = 3(x-y) = 3\cdot 4n = 2 \cdot (6n)
$$
$6n$ is clearly an integer, so we therefore see that $3x = 3y \pmod2$.

Comment: yes this is good, but how did you know to use $3x-3y$ was it intuition or something I am not seeing?

Comment: That is just the definition of $\mathrm{mod}$: $x = y \pmod n \iff x-y = kn, k \in \mathbb Z$. I edited to make this more clear.

Comment: I see it makes more sense now indeed it does.

Comment: excellent response one of the best I have seen one this site informative, rigorous,masterful

Comment: The statement "showing that $3x-3y=2k$ for an integer $k$" is precisely equivalent to the stuff I wrote after $[0]$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x-y$ is divisible by $4$ then $3x-3y$ is divisible by $2$. Really, that is all you need...

Comment: how is it if x-y is divided by 4 then 3x-3y is divisible by 2 I tried an example $5-1=4$ $15-3=12$ but how?

Comment: $3x-3y=3(x-y)$, so....

Comment: But how do you know to use 3x-3y in the first place is there a reason?

Comment: That's why I called it a "hint"

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really mean to ask is, "Why is this function well-defined?"

For it to be well-defined means that each input gives only one output, regardless of what symbol we use for the input.

So it $x=y \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ then $[0]=[3(x-y)]=[3x-3y]=[3x]-[3y]$, so $f(x)=f(y)$, and this function is well-defined.

Comment: The three is arbitrary as far as I'm concerned (there's no need for this function to be defined the way it is; it just is). In our case zero mod four goes to zero mod two because $f(0)=[3(0)]=[0]$.

Comment: I see yes that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

This function is the composite of the two functions $[x]_4\mapsto [3x]_4=[3]_4[x]_4$ and the function which takes an equivalence class mod $4$ to the projection modulo $2$, i.e. $[x]_4\mapsto [x]_2$. Since both functions are individually well-defined, so is the composition.